# Stretch Text ... if length is higher than 10 in Html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working with HTML5 Canvas lately.
Here's my JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/fknjz/17/

And here's what I have found that could be useful :

http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/145/jQuery-dynamic-text-sizing/

I need something like this :

If document.getElementById("nom").value.length > 10...then the text value would stretch -5% each time a letter is typed...so the text will start to shrink (only the width) if there's more than 10 letters typed in the textbox in the Canvas.

Does anyone knows how I could make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a more proper fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/CqAmW/ - you should minimize what you have to make a simple demo. That way it will be easier to implement. I might have a look again tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is now the update button is not working anymore. Nothing happens. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are even after, since the question is kind of vague, but did you know there is a fourth parameter for `fillText`? It fits the text to a maximum width. I updated your jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fknjz/32/.

I also added `clearRect` to clear the areas under the texts so you can update the view without making a mess.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! I didn't know there was a fourth parameter. Thank you!